# Parse out a value from json in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am trying to parse out a int value in the variable but its returning nil or 0 The value I want is from the customer_group_id. I am using swift. I have parsed out other information from the json file, but it keeps messing up at this stage.

```
  print("My Loyalty rank: " , newJson["loyalty_rank"][0]["customer_group_id"].string)
  myRank = newJson["loyalty_rank"][0]["customer_group_id"].intValue
```

Here is the json file

```
{ "id":298,
  "name":"桃子 桜",
  "total_points_earned":164, 
  "points_available_to_spend":164,
  "loyalty_rank":{ 
       "customer_group_id":9,
       "name":"Baby Bee",
       "ratio":1
   },
  "order_history":[ 
  { }
  ],
 "barcode_id":"C-00000298"
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`loyalty_rank` is `[String:AnyObject]` means its Dictionary not an array ...

try to print it like

```
     // if its string
     print("My Loyalty rank: " , newJson["loyalty_rank"]["customer_group_id"].string)

     // if its Int
     print("My Loyalty rank: " , newJson["loyalty_rank"]["customer_group_id"].intValue)
```

Better to use `if let` or `guard` like

```
    if let customerId = newJson["loyalty_rank"]["customer_group_id"].intValue{
        // customerId is int value
   }
   else{
       // not an int
   }
```

Comment: its in a nested try catch block. But thats a really good point to use a if statement if its not in a try

Comment: Sorry I couldn't accept it as the answer for 10 min for some reason. Thanks again I appreciate it. I also got lost programming too my bad.